# Python detect 'key up' event from the terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, keyboard, curses

I'm trying to write a python program to emulate a musical instrument. While the button is pressed down the note plays, when you take your finger off the button the sound automatically stops:

```
while buttonUp:
  noteSilent()

  if buttonDown:
     notePlay()
```

From what I understand the two main ways of doing this are with pygame and through curses. Pygame seems simpler but it seems to be aimed at making graphical apps whereas I'm quite content running this program purely from the command line. I've been trying to get it to work with curses but it's not really having the desired effect. This is what I currently have:

```
        while key != ord('q'):
        key = stdscr.getch()
        curses.echo()
        stdscr.addch(20, 25, key)
        stdscr.refresh()

        NoteSilent(2)

        if key == ord('a'):
            print "hello"
            NotePlay(2)
```

This doesn't seem to have the desired effect and so any advice on how to tackle this would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's a blog detailing your options here: http://www.roadsi.de/python-and-keyboard-events.html check that out.

Answer (score 1):

curses doesn't provide separate events for key presses and releases, so you'd probably be better off with pygame if you want it to work that way.

(Weird quasi-exception: ncurses and PDCurses *can* provide separate press and release events for *mouse buttons*, if you wanted to go that way. This isn't quite standard curses, and I don't know if the Python interface supports it.)

Comment: BTW, internally, PDCurses *does* work with key press and release events, and you can sort of see this on the "Input test" in testcurs -- for normal keys, the report happens on press, but for "modifier" keys (shift, etc.) it happens on release. But in the basic curses model of terminals, input comes as characters, not as key presses.